# Multiple Videos Using bigvideo.js AND Firefox Compatible

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, video

all,

I'm working on a project with the great [bigvideo.js](http://dfcb.github.io/BigVideo.js/). Nothing fancy: I just have a few short videos playing in the background. No need for navigation, captions, etc. Here is the simple code I'm using:

```
var BV = new $.BigVideo();
  BV.init();
  if (Modernizr.touch) {
    BV.show ('/images/backgrounds/bg-bob-test.jpg');
    } else {
    BV.show(['/videos/bob_video_test_color.mp4', '/videos/bob_video_test_one.mp4'],{ambient:true});
    }
  });
```

It even works with Firefox/ogg files...until I try to add multiple files as per the website's instructions:

```
$(function() {
  var BV = new $.BigVideo({useFlashForFirefox:false});
  BV.init();
  BV.show('vids/river.mp4', {altSource:'vids/river.ogv'});
});
```

My question is this: how do I combine the two, correctly? In other words, how do I call the 'altSource' for each mp4 video so that multiple videos loop in Firefox? I tried:

```
var BV = new $.BigVideo({useFlashForFirefox:false});
  BV.init();
  if (Modernizr.touch) {
    BV.show ('/images/backgrounds/bg-bob-test.jpg';
      } else {
    BV.show(['/videos/bob_video_test_one.mp4', {altSource:'/videos/bob_video_test_one.ogg'},'/videos/bob_video_test_two.mp4', {altSource:'/videos/bob_video_test_two.ogg'}],{ambient:true});
    }
});
```

To no avail. I'm sure this is a super-simple answer for someone more in the know! Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and solved it by simply checking for Firefox instead of using `altSource`:

```
$(function() {
  var BV = new $.BigVideo({useFlashForFirefox:false});
  BV.init();

  if ($.browser.msie || $.browser.opera || Modernizr.touch) {
    BV.show('video-poster.jpg');
  } else if ($.browser.mozilla) {
    BV.show('video.ogv', {ambient:true});
  } else {
    BV.show('video.mp4', {ambient:true});
  }
});
```

Comment: this was exactly what I needed, no more, no less. For those that want multiple videos, too, all browsers work as an array:

`BV.show(['video1.ogv', 'video2.ogv'], {ambient:true});`, for example.

Comment: NOTE: `$.browser` was removed with 1.9 as per http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple way of looking at which browser and if its a touch device (if you are using a recent jquery library you may need to use jquery migrate):

```
$(function() {
var BV = new $.BigVideo({useFlashForFirefox:false});

if($.browser.msie||$.browser.opera){
  BV.init();
} else {

  var vids = [
    '/assets/vids/1.mp4',           
    '/assets/vids/2.mp4',
    '/assets/vids/3.mp4'
  ];
  vids.sort(function() { return 0.5 - Math.random() }); 
  var vidsFF = [
    '/assets/vids/1.ogv',           
    '/assets/vids/2.ogv',
    '/assets/vids/3.ogv'
  ];
  vidsFF.sort(function() { return 0.5 - Math.random() }); 
  BV.init();

  if (Modernizr.touch) {
    BV.show('assets/vids/fallback.jpg');
    } else {
      if($.browser.mozilla){
        BV.show([vidsFF[0], vidsFF[1], vidsFF[2]], {ambient:true});
      } else {
        BV.show([vids[0], vids[1], vids[2]], {ambient:true});
      }
    }          
  }
});
```

You need to then set a background image cover for fallback (basically rubbish IE):

```
div {
    background: url(../images/feature-background.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='../images/feature-background.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='../images/feature-background.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the [big video source code](https://github.com/dfcb/BigVideo.js/blob/master/js/bigvideo.js) it seems like you cannot add a list for altSource, nor can you supply an object that has a source and an altSource as the first argument to `show`.

I think what you should do is listen to the bigvideo play events, manager your playlist outside of bigvideo and simply call show when the current video stops.

Maybe something like:

```
var playlist = [{source: '/videos/bob_video_test_one.mp4', altSource:'/videos/bob_video_test_one.ogg'},{source: '/videos/bob_video_test_two.mp4', altSource:'/videos/bob_video_test_two.ogg'}];

function playNext() {
  var next = playlist.shift();
  BV.show(next.source, next.altSource);
}


var player = BV.getPlayer();
player.on('ended', playNext);

playNext();
```